# Long wait when starting new activity in Android

Tags: java, android, image, android-activity

I have two activities in my Android app.

1) A list which shows items

If the user clicks on one item it opens activity 2

2) Shows a big image of the item

Now, when I click on an item and thus start the second activity there are a few seconds which the app needs to start the activity. (I suspect because of the image it needs to load). This completely destroys the flow of the use case.

What is the best practice to deal with this?

Comment: Use Glide or Picasso to load the image, or if you are loading the image from resource perform the BitmapFactory.decodeResource() in a different thread and assign the bitmap to the ImageView in the UI thread using a callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading `Bitmap`s on `Main UiThread` takes time so you have to load your bitmaps off the Ui Thread. Use the `Universal Image Loader` for loading/caching the bitmaps. See the link https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance(); // Get singleton instance
// Load image, decode it to Bitmap and display Bitmap in ImageView (or any other view 
//  which implements ImageAware interface)
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Second Activity use new Thread.. like below

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //here put your code
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                      //here set your image.
                    }
                  });
                }
            }).start();
```